# Are C++ template-functions threadsafe?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, template-function

Googling don't find anything. Are they created at point of use, or are the generic parts shared between instances?

(Same for template classes?)

Comment: The answer is "no."  Now the question becomes, do you know what "threadsafe" really means?

Comment: @John Dibling: Others have explained it better than I can; see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety

Comment: he's not asking for a textbook definition of thread safety, but instead what *you* understand by the term. Wikipedia doesn't tell us that, and that is what's important when answering this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Template functions are created at compile time. The template property is completely orthogonal to thread-safety.

Comment: Just in case that wasn't clear enough: C++ Templates are what are referred to as "code generators." By this it means that when the compiler comes across the template, it literally creates a brand new set of machine instructions for each type you use in that template. Because of this, you end up with two completely separate functions that get called. int function<type_a>() is a completely different codepath than int function<type_b>() at the machine level, even though they do the same things. So, their local variables are indeed threadsafe (different stack frames), but not anything else.

Comment: @Bryan: would different stack frames be created for typedef'd types as well? My knowledge of the compiler-innards is a bit shaky.

Comment: Typedefs introduce nothing new. They're just aliases to the referenced types.

Comment: @slashmais: Think of it this way. The <type> notation to indicate a template is really just a cool compiler trick saying "I want to write 6 functions to handle six types, that all do the same thing"... You get completely different functions. Like Peter pointed out, a typedef is just a way of referencing some other type, so you'll still get a new function specifically for that referenced type.

Answer (score 6):

They're no more or less thread-safe than any other type of function.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of thread safety being affected by this is that if `someMethod<typename T>()` wasn't thread safe then it would still be okay for a thread to operate on `someMethod<int>()` while another worked on `someMethod<std:string>()`, as long as the lack of thread-safety didn't come from their both calling into some non-templated function.

The situation where something else is guaranteeing that only one thread is doing a particular task with a particular type at a time seems pretty unlikely though.

Answer (score 2):

Template functions are simply ...templates used by the compiler to generate "normal" functions. So it's the same as normal functions, there is no difference.